# Determine @@Servicename on SQL Server, and catch error thrown by Azure

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I'd like to request the servicename of an SQL Server. Usually I do this with

```
SELECT @@SERVICENAME
```

But this don't work's on Azure hosted Databases. I'm looking for a way to determine the servicename, with a try catch fallback if I'm connected to a azure database. The usual try catch works not for me - due to compile error for the statement. How can i catch this compile error ?

[image]

Comment: Try `DECLARE @T TABLE(ServiceName NVARCHAR(255)); INSERT @T(ServiceName) EXEC ('SELECT @@SERVICENAME')`. This will still give an error, but I think you can at least catch that one.

Comment: Oh, and how about `SERVERPROPERTY('ServerName')`? This ought to not give a compilation error and just return `NULL` on Azure. Split on the backslash as required.

Comment: SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('Edition') returns "SQL Azure" on Azure, this part works fine.

Comment: Thank you Jeroen, the way with the table works for me

Answer (score 2):

This statement works in both environments without compile error:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE(ServiceName NVARCHAR(255)); 
DECLARE @Rows INT

IF SERVERPROPERTY('Edition') != 'SQL Azure'
BEGIN TRY
    INSERT @T(ServiceName) EXEC ('SELECT @@SERVICENAME')
END TRY 
BEGIN CATCH
END CATCH

SELECT @Rows = COUNT(*) FROM @T

IF @Rows = 0
INSERT @T(ServiceName) Values ('SQL Azure')

SELECT * FROM @T
```

On Local Server:

[image]

On Azure:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

USE @@version global variable instead.

```
DECLARE @version VARCHAR(200)
SELECT @version = SUBSTRING(@@version, 15,5) 
PRINT @version
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This returns `Serve` on my machine -- I'm not sure what good that's supposed to be, except as a subliminal message.

Comment: If it returns "Server" that means is an on-premise SQL Server. If it returns "Azure" the code is running on a SQL Azure database.

Comment: Except that's not what we're interested in, we want the `@@SERVICENAME`. This will contain the instance name of SQL Server if we're not on Azure. If you want the edition, `SERVERPROPERTY('Edition')` is more convenient/reliable.